# How to make traceroute trace beyond 30 hops?

Tags: networking, traceroute

Some of the servers I use `traceroute` on, are more than 30 hops away. How do I make `traceroute` trace beyond 30 hops?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From `man 1 traceroute`:

```
-m max_ttl
      Specifies  the  maximum  number of hops (max time-to-live value)
      traceroute will probe. The default is 30.
```

Comment: Additionally: the maximum number of hops is 255.

Answer (score 19):

When some location is further than 30 hops, it probably means simply that last hops does not replies when TTL exceeds.

Unless, it's a story:

```
$ traceroute -m100 216.81.59.173
traceroute to 216.81.59.173 (216.81.59.173), 100 hops max, 52 byte packets
(...)
14  episode.iv (206.214.251.1)  173.387 ms  171.638 ms  171.201 ms
15  a.new.hope (206.214.251.6)  168.299 ms  168.400 ms  172.040 ms
16  it.is.a.period.of.civil.war (206.214.251.9)  173.990 ms  172.892 ms  170.148 ms
17  rebel.spaceships (206.214.251.14)  171.745 ms  169.772 ms  169.002 ms
18  striking.from.a.hidden.base (206.214.251.17)  170.697 ms  168.263 ms  168.610 ms
19  have.won.their.first.victory (206.214.251.22)  171.065 ms  170.167 ms  265.206 ms
20  against.the.evil.galactic.empire (206.214.251.25)  170.906 ms  234.735 ms  169.272 ms
21  during.the.battle (206.214.251.30)  171.541 ms  169.632 ms  173.910 ms
22  rebel.spies.managed (206.214.251.33)  170.619 ms  170.862 ms  171.820 ms
23  to.steal.secret.plans (206.214.251.38)  171.433 ms  182.794 ms  171.130 ms
24  to.the.empires.ultimate.weapon (206.214.251.41)  171.000 ms  173.832 ms  169.343 ms
25  the.death.star (206.214.251.46)  171.819 ms  170.550 ms  168.248 ms
26  an.armored.space.station (206.214.251.49)  168.109 ms  171.418 ms  170.669 ms
27  with.enough.power.to (206.214.251.54)  169.475 ms  172.276 ms  169.378 ms
28  destroy.an.entire.planet (206.214.251.57)  170.520 ms  170.210 ms  174.096 ms
29  pursued.by.the.empires (206.214.251.62)  169.275 ms  171.433 ms  172.075 ms
30  sinister.agents (206.214.251.65)  170.922 ms  171.965 ms  171.492 ms
31  princess.leia.races.home (206.214.251.70)  171.816 ms  170.498 ms  171.694 ms
32  aboard.her.starship (206.214.251.73)  172.262 ms  168.907 ms  172.208 ms
33  custodian.of.the.stolen.plans (206.214.251.78)  171.719 ms  174.277 ms  170.684 ms
34  that.can.save.her (206.214.251.81)  171.340 ms  171.182 ms  174.110 ms
35  people.and.restore (206.214.251.86)  170.111 ms  172.270 ms  171.921 ms
36  freedom.to.the.galaxy (206.214.251.89)  172.464 ms  173.231 ms  171.365 ms
37  0-----i-------i-----0 (206.214.251.94)  173.037 ms  171.931 ms  170.092 ms
38  0------------------0 (206.214.251.97)  172.218 ms  171.107 ms  171.267 ms
39  0-----------------0 (206.214.251.102)  171.400 ms  172.031 ms  174.598 ms
40  0----------------0 (206.214.251.105)  170.030 ms  173.025 ms  171.469 ms
41  0---------------0 (206.214.251.110)  172.326 ms  171.856 ms  172.994 ms
42  0--------------0 (206.214.251.113)  170.856 ms  174.109 ms  170.936 ms
43  0-------------0 (206.214.251.118)  171.991 ms  172.868 ms  173.722 ms
44  0------------0 (206.214.251.121)  171.233 ms  169.809 ms  173.038 ms
45  0-----------0 (206.214.251.126)  171.787 ms  172.344 ms  171.002 ms
46  0----------0 (206.214.251.129)  173.352 ms  170.713 ms  173.296 ms
47  0---------0 (206.214.251.134)  171.911 ms  172.478 ms  170.493 ms
48  0--------0 (206.214.251.137)  172.383 ms  170.712 ms  174.033 ms
49  0-------0 (206.214.251.142)  169.868 ms  171.649 ms  171.364 ms
50  0------0 (206.214.251.145)  172.330 ms  169.414 ms  171.859 ms
51  0-----0 (206.214.251.150)  173.134 ms  197.696 ms  170.179 ms
52  0----0 (206.214.251.153)  173.789 ms  171.736 ms  173.433 ms
53  0---0 (206.214.251.158)  173.885 ms  173.725 ms  172.579 ms
54  0--0 (206.214.251.161)  170.834 ms  173.887 ms  171.137 ms
55  0-0 (206.214.251.166)  172.897 ms  171.225 ms  171.217 ms
56  00 (206.214.251.169)  173.286 ms  174.234 ms  171.737 ms
57  i (206.214.251.174)  173.487 ms  172.496 ms  172.307 ms
58  by.ryan.werber (206.214.251.177)  174.808 ms  173.357 ms  172.911 ms
59  blizzards.breed.ccie.creativity (206.214.251.182)  171.963 ms  174.378 ms  172.888 ms
60  please.try.again.tracerote.to.obiwan.scrye.net (206.214.251.185)  171.410 ms  173.825 ms  171.782 ms
61  read.more.at.beaglenetworks.net (206.214.251.190)  174.625 ms *  175.767 ms
```

Comment: My reactions to this, in order: Wow, neat! What a waste of IPv4 space. Nah, it's worth it.

Comment: Other destinations that exceed 30 hops might also be looping, which is what the TTL was originally meant to protect against.

Comment: @cpugeniusmv Try tracerouting to any other of the addresses, e.g. 206.214.251.22 and it doesn't seem to work.  I suspect there's some clever ICMP fakery going on here

Comment: @DigitalTrauma might be they are simulating hops, but still the address range has to be assigned and routed (or redirected only for ICMP) to whoever did this and the reverse DNS records have to resolve to the prologue lines. For anything sane, 30 hops are probably a working upper limit.

Comment: If you try it from a Windows host (tracert -h 100 216.81.59.173), the replies are case-sensitive. The story is on [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/15/star_wars_traceroute/).

Comment: @cpugeniusmv Does it indicate problems with host's network connectivity?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov not necessarily. If you ultimately reach your destination somewhere between 31 and 99 hops it's a little strange, but functional. Could be typical for far away international hosts or routing through VPNs or maybe TOR. If you're seeing stars (* * *) all the way to 100, though, you've hit a string of routers and/or a destination that doesn't respond to traceroute requests.

Comment: For what it's worth, the default TTL in IP is typically 64.

Comment: OMG!! I came searching for a quick answer and now I am entertained for hours!!!

Comment: `bad.horse`        (`-m40`)

Answer (score -1):

> set global curhoplimit=255, is my command for promt. yoiu need to put in the propper menue to do so. at least that my command bios. but it would not save for me when i changed the value. ,also my command is called (tracert)